# atm code issue with displaying pre existing balances

Tags: c

I have an assignment where i'm supposed to simulate an ATM machine. The issue i'm running into is that my code only shows the last variable embedded within the variable "currBal" and not all 3. I have an idea that i might possibly need to use a pointer to differentiate which account to pull from but i'm lost from then on.

IE: double currBal = (checking,savings,**credit**);

when running the code the pre existing balance shows only the credit amount of -750 for checking savings and credit (should only show for credit, while checkings and savings should show their respective #defined amounts before deposits and withdrawals.) The only things i'm missing now is showing all 3 pre existing balances,and making sure the withdrawal and deposits work for their respective accounts.

Thank you for the help!

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1

#include <stdio.h>
#define CREDITLIMIT -2000
#define credit -750.00
#define savings 3750.00
#define checking 897.23


    //* Displays the list of user’s options available
    //** Displays the user’s selections and sets the value of the choice
    void entryMenu(int *choice);


//Prompts the user for the amount of their deposit and updates the selected account
void MakeDeposit(double *currBal);


//Asks the user if they want another transaction
void DoMore(char * doAgain);




//Displays the types of account they would like to access and sets the
//value of the chosen account type
void ChoiceMenu(char *acctType);


//Prompts the user for the amount of the withdrawal, determines if there are
//sufficient funds and updates the selected account if funds are dispensed
void MoneyToSpend(double *currBal);


//Displays the user’s current account balance for the selected account
void DisplayBalance(double currBal);


int main()
{
    double currBal = (checking, credit, savings);
    int choice;
    char doAgain = 0;
    char acctType;




    while (1) {
        printf("Welcome to MYBANK\n");
        printf("Please choose from the following menu\n");
        do {
            entryMenu(&choice);
            switch (choice) {
            case 1://Deposit
                ChoiceMenu(&acctType);
                MakeDeposit(&currBal);
                DoMore(&doAgain);
                break;
            case 2://withdrawal
                ChoiceMenu(&acctType);
                MoneyToSpend(&currBal);
                DoMore(&doAgain);
                break;
            case 3://account balance
                ChoiceMenu(&acctType);
                DisplayBalance(currBal);
                DoMore(&doAgain);
                break;
                //choices that are not 1,2,3
            default:
                printf("invalid Choice");
                DoMore(&doAgain);
            }
        } while (doAgain == 'Y' || doAgain == 'y');
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


//*Displays the list of user’s options available
//**Displays the user’s selections and sets the value of the choice
void entryMenu(int *choice)
{
    printf("1 - DEPOSIT \n");
    printf("2 - WITHDRAWAL \n");
    printf("3 - CHECK ACCOUNT BALANCE \n");
    printf("Important: ");
    printf("To transfer money first select \n(2) for WITHDRAWAL, then \n(1) for DEPOSIT\n");
    scanf(" %d", choice);
}


//Prompts the user for the amount of their deposit and updates the selected account
void MakeDeposit(double *currBal)
{
    float deposit;
    printf("Please enter the amount of the deposit: ");
    scanf("%f", &deposit);


    *currBal += deposit;

    printf("Thank you, please take your cash and receipt\n");
}


//Asks the user if they want another transaction
void DoMore(char * doAgain)
{
    int choice;
    printf("Would you like to make another transaction?\n");
    printf("(Y)es / (N)o ? \n");
    scanf(" %c", doAgain);
}


//Displays the types of account they would like to access and sets the
//value of the chosen account type
void ChoiceMenu(char *acctType)
{
    printf("Please select account: \n");
    printf("Choose C for Checking\n");
    printf("Choose S for Savings\n");
    printf("Choose R for Credit\n");
    scanf(" %c", acctType);
}


//Prompts the user for the amount of the withdrawal, determines if there are
//sufficient funds and updates the selected account if funds are dispensed
void MoneyToSpend(double *currBal, char acctType)
{
    float withdrawal;
    {
        printf("Please enter the amount of the withdrawal: ");
        scanf("%f", &withdrawal);
        {
            if (*currBal < withdrawal)
            {
                printf("You do not have enough\n\n");

            }
            else if (*currBal > withdrawal)
            {
                *currBal -= withdrawal;
            }

        }
    }
}





//Displays the user’s current account balance for the selected account
void DisplayBalance(double currBal)

{
    printf("\nYou have %.1f in your account\n", currBal);
}
```

Comment: "variable embedded within the variable "currBal"" and `double currBal = (checking, credit, savings);` are totally wrong. That is not how C works. You can't assign multiple values to a single base type variable. You need to declare a struct type. Perhaps you need to go back to your C text book to review these fundamental concepts.

Comment: ok, so i went ahead and changed the declared variable to just double currBal; double credit = -750; double savings = 3750; double checking = 897.23; now when i run the code to check the pre existing balance it crashes. I feel like the values are not being recognized and im confused as to what to do.

Comment: Use a debugger. Use debug print statements. Learn to debug effectively. You can't just dump your whole program here and expect someone else to debug it all for you. You need to do your own debugging to narrow down the problem first as much as you can. And then ask a *specific* question.